# How can I disable the mini-cart if the basket contains too many products?

Tags: magento2, frontend, mini-cart

I am working on a wholesale website in Magento 2 and have noticed the front-end performance drops off massively when the mini-cart has to render too many items **(over say, 20 different SKUs).**

I'm sure I can figure out how to hide the cart myself if there are more than a certain number of items but I was wondering if there's an 'official' way to do this?

I found a method in **`Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar`** which seems to get a config value for this purpose:

```
/**
 * Return max visible item count for minicart
 *
 * @return int
 */
private function getMiniCartMaxItemsCount()
{
    return (int)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('checkout/sidebar/count', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

However this doesn't seem to have the intended effect.

I've traced it through to **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js** where the value is assigned to the mini-cart in **`initSidebar()`** but it only seems to adjust the *height* (CSS) of the mini-cart?

This would obviously have no effect on the performance of the page...

Do I need to come up with my own add-on somewhere in the render chain instead?

Comment: In Magento by default it shows 10 products in mini cart so in your case all are coming in list?

Comment: @CharulTyagi Yes, it's showing the whole cart, could this be the theme interfering with the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness, I accomplished this for now by modifying `Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html` in my theme and adding a Knockout `if` to check item count (not the total item quantity) and display a message if it exceeds the defined limit rather than rendering the items:

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Recently added item(s)' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
    <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('items').length < 16 -->
            <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartParam('items'), as: 'item' }">
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </ol>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('items').length > 15 -->
            <p>Please use the link above to view your basket.</p>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```